# wkhtmltopdf installation on cent os server

Tags: centos, wkhtmltopdf

I'm trying to install wkhtmltopdf on CentOS 64-bit box.
I did the following:

```
$ wget {relavant url to binary from link above}
$ tar -xvf {filename of above wget'd file}
$ ./wkhtmltopdf-amd64 http://www.google.com example.pdf
```

And i got:

error while loading shared libraries: libXrender.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

I tried installing libXrender.so.1 using yum install.
I can see libXrender.so.1 sym ink in /usr/lib

Please help.

Thanks

Comment: Which link was it; meaning 0.9.9 or 0.11.0? Asking because there's a possibly related ticket in the wkhtmltopdf issue tracker: https://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/issues/detail?id=968&q=libXrender.so -- maybe try 0.9.9? The project is not very active although it has many users - not many contributors at the moment.